# How to extract and parse commands of shellscript to file?

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following program in `Shell Script`:

```
#!/bin/sh

max=9
for i in `seq 1 $max`
do
    sudo -u ${USERNAME} heroku config --app mws-usp-app0${i}
done

max=50
for i in `seq 10 $max`
do
    sudo -u ${USERNAME} heroku config --app mws-usp-app${i}
done
```

The result of each line of the for command is:

```
=== mws-usp-app01 Config Vars
CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL:         mysql://<user>:<password>@us-cdbr-iron-east-04.cleardb.net/heroku_cf843140f07f0a2?reconnect=true
DATABASE_URL:                 postgres://...:...@ec2-23-21-73-32.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dalmmfh5cs6nqa
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PURPLE_URL: postgres://...:...@ec2-50-19-219-148.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/de4hk500aj9f1q
JAVA_OPTS:                    -XX:+UseCompressedOops
=== mws-usp-app02 Config Vars
CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL:         mysql://<user>:<password>@us-cdbr-iron-east-04.cleardb.net/heroku_cf843140f07f0a2?reconnect=true
DATABASE_URL:                 postgres://...:...@ec2-23-21-73-32.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dalmmfh5cs6nqa
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PURPLE_URL: postgres://...:...@ec2-50-19-219-148.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/de4hk500aj9f1q
JAVA_OPTS:                    -XX:+UseCompressedOops
...
=== mws-usp-app50 Config Vars
CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL:         mysql://<user>:<password>@us-cdbr-iron-east-04.cleardb.net/heroku_b154acff411bcfc?reconnect=true
DATABASE_URL:                 postgres://...:...@ec2-23-21-73-32.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dalmmfh5cs6nqa
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PURPLE_URL: postgres://...:...@ec2-54-243-204-86.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d5gngl61fsq95o
JAVA_OPTS:                    -XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

How to parse `CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL` to get all values of `<user>` and `<password>` and put them inside a text file separated by white space?

**Note:** The `<user>` and `<password>` are alphanumeric characters only. One example of `<user> = b69ab75f269r50` and `<password> = c6f5230r6`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
... | perl -nE '/CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL:.*mysql:..(.*?):(.*?)@/ and say "$1:$2"'
```

Find your pattern (`/.../`) and print the relevant captured elements (`and say ...`)

Comment: Hello @JJoao, I am a beginner in shellscript and tried to execute the command: `echo heroku config --app mws-usp-app0${i} | perl -nE '/CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL:.*mysql:..(.*?):(.*?)@/ and say $1,$2'`, but it did not work.

Comment: @ricardoramos,  f your script is named `S`,  try `S | perl -nE '/CL .... `

Comment: Hello @JJoao, printed all together how do I print with a space separating `<user>` from `<password>`?

Comment: @ricardoramos, I update changing the output format; now they are separated by a ":" (you can easily adapt to your favorite format)

Answer (score 0):

This should help (untested)

```
./<your-shell-script> | grep "^CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL" | awk -F: '{print $3":"$4}' > output-file
```

Comment: You'll need to strip the `//` from the username part.

Comment: Hello @Jeff Schaller, I tested here, generated the file. However, the file is blank :(

Comment: I didn't write this answer; I just formatted it to look more like code. The problem may be that your input says "CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL" while this answer is (currently) grepping for "CLEAR_DATABASE_URL"